# Unexpected color changes after upgrading to ggplot2 3.3.4

Tags: r, ggplot2

The picture shows the difference before and after upgrading ggplot2 from ver.3.3.3 to ver. 3.3.4 [image]

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(name = structure(c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("5303 B", "5303 A", 
"5302 B", "5302 A", "5301 B", "5301 A", "5202 B", "5202 A", "5201 B", 
"5201 A", "5101 B", "5101 A"), class = "factor"), stadio = c(2, 
2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 
1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 7, 9, 9, 11, 11, 1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 7, 9, 9, 11, 11
), variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("start_date", 
"end_date"), class = "factor"), value = c("15/10/2021", "03/01/2022", 
"03/01/2022", "30/03/2022", "30/03/2022", "30/03/2023", "30/03/2023", 
"15/09/2023", "15/09/2023", "29/12/2023", "15/10/2021", "03/01/2022", 
"03/01/2022", "30/03/2022", "30/03/2022", "30/03/2023", "30/03/2023", 
"15/09/2023", "15/09/2023", "29/12/2023", "26/11/2021", "14/01/2022", 
"14/01/2022", "30/06/2022", "30/06/2022", "30/03/2023", "30/03/2023", 
"15/09/2023", "15/09/2023", "29/12/2023", "26/11/2021", "14/01/2022", 
"14/01/2022", "30/06/2022", "30/06/2022", "30/03/2023", "30/03/2023", 
"15/09/2023", "15/09/2023", "29/12/2023"), rating = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2", "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(df, aes(as.POSIXct(as.Date(value, "%d/%m/%Y")), name, colour = factor(stadio,levels=1:11))) +
  guides(alpha = "none",
         colour = guide_legend(
           override.aes = list(size = 4))) +
  geom_line(aes(size=rating, alpha=rating)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(.5,1)) +
  labs(colour="(Actual/Baseline)", x = "", y = "") +
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("1", "3", "7","9","11"), values = brewer.pal(11,"PiYG")) +
  scale_size_manual(breaks = levels(df$rating),  values = as.integer(levels(df$rating)), guide = "none")
```

Comment: It's probably this change from the [changelog](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/): "Manual scales now allow named vectors passed to values to contain fewer elements than existing in the data. Elements not present in values will be set to NA (@thomasp85, #3451)"

Comment: Should be fixed in development version of ggplot2: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/4619

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help:

> "values: a set of aesthetic values to map data values to. The values
> will be matched in order (usually alphabetical) with the limits of the
> scale, or with breaks if provided. If this is a named vector, then the
> values will be matched based on the names instead. Data values that
> don't match will be given na.value."

So in this line:

```
scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("1", "3", "7","9","11"), values = brewer.pal(11,"PiYG"))
```

You have 5 breaks defined so ggplot is only using the first 5 colors of the palette.  If you remove "breaks = c("1", "3", "7","9","11")" the plot is correct but not the legend is displaying all 11 values.

To plot all 11 colors and have the legend only display half of the values in the legend, you need to define a function to select which values to display.

```
oddones <- function(x) {
   ifelse(as.integer(x)%%2, x, "")
}

ggplot(df, aes(as.POSIXct(as.Date(value, "%d/%m/%Y")), name, colour = factor(stadio,levels=1:11))) +
   guides(alpha = "none",  colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4))) +
   geom_line(aes(size=rating, alpha=rating)) +
   scale_alpha_manual(values=c(.5,1)) +
   labs(colour="(Actual/Baseline)", x = "", y = "") +
   scale_colour_manual(breaks = oddones, values = brewer.pal(11,"PiYG")) +
   scale_size_manual(breaks = levels(df$rating),  values = as.integer(levels(df$rating)), guide = "none")
```

Comment: This excerpt from help is exactly the same as in version 3.3.2 that I currently work with. How did you know you had to use a function?

Comment: Sorry, It has been awhile but I had a similar problem in the past and needed to relearn it it. From the breaks entry on the help page: "A function that takes the limits as input and returns breaks as output".

Comment: Very tricky! I dοn't see anywhere a clue that a "character vector" and a "function" can have so different behavior. Seems to me more like a bug, than a useful enhancement.